# How to avoid reading the whole URL into the memory in R by being selective in lines

Tags: r, io

I am new to R scripting. I am trying to read some data from a url which has a list of all the available rain gauges. Following are a few lines of the file:

ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833   10.1    ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD
ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833   19.2    ST JOHNS
AE000041196  25.3330   55.5170   34.0    SHARJAH INTER. AIRP            GSN     41196

I am reading the file using read.fwf as it is a fixed width file. but I don't need the whole file, I want to be selective and save the lines which has some specific criteria like starting with US. Is that possible in R? If possible, would it be preferred to do so? Any comment would be appreciate.

Comment: Most R functions do not allow you to filter data as you are reading it in. I think the `sqldf` package might but it also might not read data directly from URLs. You're better off either filtering your data before reading into R via some other program or just reading it all and filtering within R.

Comment: Does the website lay out data just like this? This seems like a transformed xml output or html table. Consider saving data to txt, csv, xml, dat, raw etc. then use the [readlines function](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/s133/Read.html).